# Bootstrap form doesn't work

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap

I take form example from http://getbootstrap.com, and add hidden input. `result.php` file has `$_REQUEST` in it. I see just hidden value.

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="/requests/result.php" method="post">
        <div class="form-group" id="formGroupSubject">
            <label for="inputSubjectx" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Тема</label>
            <div class="col-sm-10">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubjectx" placeholder="Тема заявки" value="title" />
            <span id="errorBlockSubject" class="help-block"></span>
        </div>
     </div>
<input type="hidden" name="iblockId" value="'.$arFields["IBLOCK_ID"].'" />
      <div class="form-group" >
        <div class="col-sm-offset-9 col-sm-2" col-sm-offset-1>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: `<form>` are used to send datas using THEIR NAME. If you don't put name to the inputs, you won't send any datas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no `name` attribute for the other `input` fields. Add `name` to them.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputSubjectx" placeholder="Тема заявки" value="title" name="inputSubjectx"> // Or whatever it should be
```